# Sign PowerShell script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, code-signing

I'm looking to create a web service to sign powershell scripts for use within an intranet. Is it possible to replicate the block of encoded text at the end of a script that set-authenticodesignature creates?

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.setauthenticodesignaturecommand_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
seems to say no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET is not your friend on this one. No support that I've been able to find - I've searched on multiple occasions

1. This is a VB example that uses Win32 API. Could be adapted to Powershell. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/02/20/how-to-sign-exe-files-with-an-authenticode-certificate-vb-net.aspx
2. The blog mentions CAPICOM.SignedCode. If you already have CAPICOM installed or that is an option, I'd go with that. I personally prefer using COM over Win32 from PS.
3. Suspect you don't want to do this, but FWIW, Mono does have support for Authenticode signing built in. I was able to cut, paste, and edit a big blob of Mono C# code a while back and get it to work on Powershell.

Comment: In case you do want to do this, I have the following hack - https://gist.github.com/voltagex/5835833

Comment: @voltagex nice hack. Your act got me looking through reflector and I saw that in System.Security.Cryptography there CAPI, CAPIBase, CAPIMethods, and CAPINative classes. All private of course, but available thru reflection

Comment: I hope you come back, as the SignCode tool in my GitHub repo is much better and uses the same APIs that powershell does.

Answer (score 2):

But you could invoke [powershell from c#](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42716). Using this functionality you can easy call 
Set-AuthenticodeSignature from your code

Comment: Thanks, this is a possibility. I'm interested to see whether the Managed API can do it - letting me sign a PowerShell script as a MemoryStream

Answer (score 2):

Here is, how they do it https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/d8f8f0a8bcbadb357f9eaafbb797278ebe07d7cc/src/System.Management.Automation/security/Authenticode.cs

In this file you can find the signaturehelper class with the following function:

```
internal static Signature SignFile(SigningOption option,
                                           string fileName,
                                           X509Certificate2 certificate,
                                           string timeStampServerUrl,
                                           string hashAlgorithm)
```

ok, i am a little bit late now ;-)

Best Regards