# Sign a Powershellscript with C# / .NetCore

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

for my complex system i am looking for a way to sign a powershellscript not with **powershell** but with **C# / .NetCore**

here the **Powershell** version:

```
$cert=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My -CodeSigningCert
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath PsTestInternet2.ps1 -Certificate $cert
```

My current solution starts a **Powershell console** with

```
process.start
```

**Why do I want to sign with C# and not Powershell?**

1. my system is an intranet service
2. the user can compile a script from snippets in the app and select additional installation files
3. now the script is signed and compiled with the installation files to an exe (C# console project - compiled at runtime with dotnet)
4. this exe can be controlled by the user (the exe has switches to examine the update)
5. now this exe (update) is distributed via wsus and arrives on user computers and installs the installation files with the script.

All this is a nice system, but it would be even nicer if I would not have to save the script first to sign it with

***process-start => powershell***

As you can read above I am not looking for someone to do my homework, but someone who is experienced enough to tell me how to sign the script with C# without using a powershellpipe.

Thanks a lot
Best regards

Comment: I don't think it's possible directly from C# as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17227679/9363973) Q&A. Instead I think you'll need to continue to use powershell, but instead of doing it manually, you could use something like [`CliWrap`](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) to make your life easier

Comment: thank you for your thoughts, but it has to be possible. Because Set-Authenticode is programmed in C#.
It uses System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates with timestamp server and hashalgorithm

Comment: these involved classes and methods I could find out, now I am looking for the namespace they are in ;-) SignatureHelper.GetSignature(filePath, null);SignatureHelper.SignFile(option,
                                                filePath,
                                                Certificate,
                                                TimestampServer,
                                                _hashAlgorithm);

Comment: thanks for the tip regarding CliWrap, it's a absolutely nice one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I've invested more time and figured out the underlying technology, I found the solution on GitHub in Microsoft's code.

Up to now it was also claimed here on stackoverflow that it is not possible.

Here is, how they do it
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/d8f8f0a8bcbadb357f9eaafbb797278ebe07d7cc/src/System.Management.Automation/security/Authenticode.cs

In this file you can find the signaturehelper class with the following function:

```
internal static Signature SignFile(SigningOption option,
                                           string fileName,
                                           X509Certificate2 certificate,
                                           string timeStampServerUrl,
                                           string hashAlgorithm)
```

Sorry if anyone minds, I found the solution so quickly. At least now I've shared it.

**Edit:**

> Because of the underlying function, the file must still be saved
> first. So the advantage is marginal.

Comment: How did you end up implementing this? Did you put the code in your own repository under your own namespace so the internal is no longer an issue, or is there a way to call this via via?

Comment: i have copied the code so internal is for me not relevant :-)
Copy all what is relevant for this function and use it in your project